# How do I write an expected value in measure theory?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, conditional-expectation

How can I express the expectation of a function involving the conditional probability distribution $p(x'|x)$, like $\mathbb E_{p}\left[1-p\left(x'|x\right)\right]$, as a general integral over the measure $p$ that can be used for both discrete and continuous cases? Is it valid to represent it as:

$$
\mathbb E_{p}\left[1-p\left(x'|x\right)\right]=\int_{\mathcal X}\left(1-p\left(x'|x\right)\right)\mathrm{d}p?
$$

Comment: At the moment, it looks like the random thing you are taking the expectation over is the conditional distribution $p$, i.e. $\mathcal X$ is a family of functions (representing conditional distributions) that have some probability of being selected.  Is that intended?

Comment: So $X\in\mathcal X$ is a random variable. $x$ and $x'$ are value of this random variable. The conditional part is not even that important, I'm just wondering about how to write the expectation when $p$ itself appears.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your notation.  If $x$ and $x'$ are values of the random variable $X$, does $p(x'|x)$ mean the probability that $X = x'$ given $X = x$?  Or if $x$ and $x'$ are meant to be realizations of two different random variables (say $X$ and $Y$), would $p(x'|x)$ mean the probability that $Y = x'$ given $X = x$?  Either way, what is random in the expression $p(x'|x)$?

Comment: Yes sorry, it's the last thing you said: $x$ is a realisation of the random variable $X$ and $x'$ is the realisation of $X'$. So $p$ is a conditional distribution of $X'$ and the expected value is a function of $x$.